# Android properly closing processes

Tags: java, android

I am using these codes to run a screencap feature on my android app, it is able to capture the screencap and convert it into a bitmap to be used, however after running it a few times. the app becomes slower and I have no idea why

Is it caused by these codes running continuous and leaving processes in the memory? And if so how do I properly close them?

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
outputStream.write("/system/bin/screencap -p\n");
outputStream.flush();
Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(process.getInputStream());
outputStream.write("exit\n");
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Any reason you're not doing something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/608347

Comment: You should terminate the processes when you're done with them. `process.destroy();`. This will close any streams associated with them, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jdk 7 you can use the try-with-resources approach:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
try (OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
     InputStream in = process.getInputStream()) {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    outputStream.write("/system/bin/screencap -p\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.write("exit\n");
    Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
}
```

By putting the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in the try block's parentheses, both streams will automatically be closed at the end of the try block.

Alternatively you can use the Google Guava library (which is awesome, btw).  I can post that code if you need it, but its on their site here (https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained)

Comment: do i have to end the process too?

Comment: I believe you will want to kill that Process once your're done.  Yes. `process#destroy()`